# What could be causing my download/ping issues?

Tags: networking, ping, isp

Disclaimer, I will be referring to **ping** as the result of the `ping 8.8.8.8` command.

I am connected via FTTH to a (relatively) newly constructed Gigabit fiber network (~2020).
For several months it worked fine, with ping usually < 10ms and good download speed (up to 400mbps).
Lately however the performance greatly degraded as a few months ago a serious storm took down the line for about a week, and when repairs were finally done I started noticing ping increase (20-30ms); since then it has been getting progressively worse especially during peak hours (20:00 to 24:00), now sitting at 60-100ms ping with >10% packet loss.

I have contacted my ISP wich at first claimed it was normal "peak hour behavior", when presented with more evidence acknowledged the problem but claimed it was not theirs and had contacted the network owner*.
My upload speed is mostly unaffected.

* It is a public society which only builds and maintains the infrastructure.

**To summarize**: solid connection until a storm hit, after repairs performance dropped to almost unusable over the course of a month.

What could be causing this problem?
I am no network expert, but my guess is that my ISP can't handle the amount of people connected, generating heavy congestion.
If so, would switch to another ISP help?

Comment: [Ping is _not_ a tool to measure network performance](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16777/small-variations-in-ping-on-a-lan/16822#16822). From the first glance it looks like something in the network isn't capable of handling the load, but whether it's the ISP infrastructure or the society's can't be determined. It's impossible to determine also whether changing ISP would help - if the issue is with your current ISP:s infra, it would, but if it's in the one the society maintains and is used by other ISPs as well it won't. Why don't you contact the society directly?

Comment: This really is a question for your ISP, as only they know the infrastructure. For SuperUser, this is only guesswork and will attract opinion based answers mostly.

Comment: 10% packet loss isn't "normal peak hour behavior" unless your ISP's lines are _seriously_ congested (e.g. if they couldn't repair something in time and had to shift a lot of traffic to backup links), but it doesn't sound like that was the case. Can you test `ping` against hosts that are as few hops away as you can find (according to traceroute hop count)? For example, the ISP's own DNS servers, or Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 (which is often directly peered with many ISPs). This would, at least, rule out problems with the ISP's connectivity to the outside world.

Comment: @Peregrino69  PING is absolutely a tool to measure network performance.  The raw data is crude, and can be prioritised, but plotted over time it shows both performance and gives a baseline for packet loss, which can be interpolated to an indication of saturation and performance - I have received significant credits from Telcos from my monitored ping results, and have also discovered changes in routes and performance with the same.   Ping is certainly not the only, or even the best tool for performance, but it is an extremely valuable tool.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that can be causing the behaviour, from bad hardware to congested links to routing issues.

I would suggest using something like MTR / WinMTR and providing the results over at minimum a 5 minute period to us.  This will help work out where congestion is coming in, and can narrow down the scope of the problem.  (MTR is like a combination of ping and traceroute - so it shows the hops, latency and packet loss - This will help ascertain if the issue is on your LAN, between yourself and your ISP, or the ISP and the outside world).

It does sound like the ISP is suffering heavy congestion on their links though - maybe a shared link between you and them.